# How to copy an arraylist to not reflecting changes in the original list?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I copy a list to another list, and make changes to the objects contained in the new list, without affecting the objects in the old list?

```
class Foo {
   String title;
   void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
}

List<Foo> original;
List<Foo> newlist = new ArrayList<Foo>(original);

for (Foo foo : newlist) {
   foo.setTitle("test"); //this will also affect the objects in original list.
                         //how can I avoid this?
}
```

Comment: You'd have to clone the objects in original list and add them to the new list

Comment: you can clone but, it may not the solution, try searching `deep copy` and `shallow copy`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to clone the objects, but then you have to implement a clone method for it to work.  In other words, there is not a simple, general turnkey solution.

```
List<Foo> original;
List<Foo> newList=new ArrayList<Foo>();

for (Foo foo:original){
    newList.add(foo.clone();
}

//Make changes to newList
```

In the listed case clone could be:

```
class Foo {

    String title;

    void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    Foo clone(Foo foo){
        Foo result=new Foo();
        result.setTitle(foo.title);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Foo> deepCopy(ArrayList<Foo> obj)throws Exception
{
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
  baos.writeObject(obj);
  oos.close();
  ByteArrayInputStream bins = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
  ObjectInputStream oins = new ObjectInputStream(bins);
  ArrayList<Foo> ret =  (ArrayList<Foo>)oins.readObject();
  oins.close();
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is nice in general, but I'm using GWT on the client side, so unfortunately I found out I cannot use this...